# Problem reprojecting LIDAR data with Liblas

Tags: coordinate-system, lidar, liblas

I am currently trying to reproject a LIDAR file (.las) using the Open-Source LibLAS, compiled on a Scientific Linux server.

The Original data is in Oregon Lambert, NAD83 (EPSG:2992), and I am trying to reproject it to UTM WGS 84, Zone 10 N (EPSG:32610).

However, when I use the --t_srs option, I get the following error:

"error: X scale and offset combination is insufficient to represent the data"

I am suspecting it has to do with the integer values stored and the distance of translation.

How do I get it to work? Is there anything I have to change in the header information?

Regards,

Edit: Here is the command line I am using (lasinfo detects the original EPSG, so no need to specify it):

> ./las2las -i path/to/input/folder/*.las -olas -odir path/to/output -v
> --t_srs EPSG:32610

Result:

> $ Setting output SRS to EPSG:32610
>
> $ error: X scale and offset
> combination is insufficient to represent the data

Comment: could you please paste the exact command line you are using?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite difficult to help you without do some checks on the input file. Try to write a complete command even it seems useless:

```
./las2las -v in.las output.las -offset 0 0 0 --t_srs EPSG:32610 --scale 0.0000001 0.0000001 0.0000001 --a_srs EPSG:2992
```